# How to distinguish between different service objects under the same class?

Tags: eclipse, osgi

Different service providers could register different service implements for the same service class. When I want to use the service, how to distinguish between these implements ?

Comment: How are you accessing the services? With [ServiceTracker](https://docs.osgi.org/javadoc/r6/core/org/osgi/util/tracker/ServiceTracker.html) you can specify a filter to match properties specified by the service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ServiceReference](https://docs.osgi.org/javadoc/osgi.core/8.0.0/index.html?org/osgi/framework/ServiceReference.html) object for a service will provide access to metadata for the service including the service properties specified when the service was registered, and also the bundle which registered the service.